# How to convert pscustomobject to string?

Tags: powershell

I have the following

```
$Json = '{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}'
$Sql = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

this `$Sql` outputs

```
Authentication Kind Username Password    EncryptConnection
------------------- -------- --------    -----------------
UsernamePassword    someID1  Yu#gh456!ts              True
```

now i want to convert this back to string (after having some some changes on the password)

> {"Authentication
>   Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"******","EncryptConnection":true}

```
$Sql = $Sql | out-string
```

however, `out-string` doesnt do the job. this is what i get back

```
Authentication Kind Username Password    EncryptConnection
------------------- -------- --------    -----------------
UsernamePassword    someID1  ******              True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterpart to `ConvertFrom-Json` is (surprise, surprise) [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-5.1)!

```
PS C:\> $Sql |ConvertTo-Json
{
    "Authentication Kind":  "UsernamePassword",
    "Username":  "someID1",
    "Password":  "Yu#gh456!ts",
    "EncryptConnection":  true
}
```

use the `-Compress` switch parameter if you want a non-pretty version:

```
PS C:\> $Sql |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}
```

If you want a shallow native text representation of a psobject use `LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo()` (this is what you see error output from the pipeline binder for example):

```
PS C:\> [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($Sql, [string])
@{Authentication Kind=UsernamePassword; Username=someID1; Password=Yu#gh456!ts; EncryptConnection=True}
```

Comment: although, what if it wasnt json in the first place, what it was a string that was made a pscustomobject. how do you convert it back to a string? not relevant or too crucial for my case here but for other future visotrs, this may be a good question/answer :)

Comment: Updated the answer, although for any serious serialization purposes I'd **strongly** recommend using json, xml or (if the objects are flat like in your example) csv.

Comment: oh i meant without @ , because @{ symbolizes pscustomobject

Comment: As I said, `ConvertTo-Json`, `Export-Clixml` (or `Export-Xml`), `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv` are the tools to use

Comment: @Cataster, you can't just make a `PSCustomObject` of every `String`. The string need to contain a certain format to define the separate property names and values. Usually this is a serialized ("Stringified") object such as JSON, XML, or a something like a PowerShell expression. Do you have a specific string  in mind?

Comment: @iRon for example this: 'Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;' | ConvertFrom-Json
but nvm, i just tested it out locally and it returns exception ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: Connection Timeout.

Comment: @Cataster So you're looking for something like `ConvertFrom-StringData`? `'Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;' -replace ';',[System.Environment]::NewLine |ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen interesting. is there a convertto-stringdata to revert back from hashtable? ( with gettype().name returns that its a hashtable)

Answer (score 0):

Override ToString() method

Add-Member  -MemberType ScriptMethod -InputObject $myObject -Name ToString -Value { "My custom Object ";Get-Date -DisplayHint Date } -Force

Must use Force to override!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look how it looks in the console, but in Format-List, and not in JSON format like @mathias-r-jessen's answer, use the following:

```
PS C:\> Write-Output "$(Out-string -InputObject ($sql|Format-List))"

Authentication Kind : UsernamePassword
Username            : someID1
Password            : Yu#gh456!ts
EncryptConnection   : True
```